# Using Namegroups with literal less-than-greater-than brackets

Tags: regex

I have a regex that looks basically like this:

```
<(title|head)>(.*?)(String)(.*?<\/\1>
```

I am trying to use name groups to identify the parts

```
(?P<TITLE>(<(title|head)>))(.*?)(?P<NAME>(String))(.*?<\/\1>
```

This works when I don't use the TITLE name group:

```
(<(title|head)>)(.*?)(?P<NAME>(String))(.*?<\/\1>
```

but when I use the TITLE name group while I don't get errors I suddenly lose my match. Any ideas on how to capture the part of the regex using <>? I've tried escaping the > as well:

```
(?P<TITLE>(\<(title|head)\>))(.*?)(?P<NAME>(String))(.*?<\/\1>
```

to no avail

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### Numbering of mixed named and numbered capturing groups

The regex tools which support named capture (Python, .NET, PCRE/PHP, Perl 5.10, etc.) handle the numbering of mixed named and numbered capturing groups in different ways. The .NET flavor first numbers all the numbered (non-named) from left to right, then goes back and numbers the named groups. However, the PCRE/PHP flavor counts the named and numbered capturing groups in one pass from left to right. Here is your regex, (fixed - added missing closing parentheses), and fully commented in both flavors showing how the mixed capture groups are numbered:

### PCRE/PHP Mixed captures numbering example:

```php
$re_php = '%
    # PCRE/PHP mixed capture numbering example.
    (?P<TITLE>          # $1: = $TITLE:
      (                 # $2:
        <(title|head)>  # $3:
      )                 # End $2:
    )                   # End $1: = $TITLE:
    (.*?)               # $4:
    (?P<NAME>           # $5: = $NAME:
      (String)          # $6:
    )                   # End $5: = $NAME:
    (.*?)               # $7:
    </\1>               # Error! Should be "\3".
    %x';
```

### .NET Mixed captures numbering example:

```php
Regex re_csharp = new Regex(@"
    # .NET mixed capture numbering example.
    (?<TITLE>           # $TITLE: = $6:
      (                 # $1:
        <(title|head)>  # $2:
      )                 # End $1:
    )                   # End $TITLE: = $6:
    (.*?)               # $3:
    (?<NAME>            # $NAME: = $7:
      (String)          # $4:
    )                   # End $NAME: = $7:
    (.*?)               # $5:
    </\1>               # Error! Should be '\2'.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

As Tim eluded, there are other issues with your regex as well, but I will not address them here.

### Bottom line:

Its best to just not mix the two types of capturing groups. Use either all named or all numbered capturing groups. Your life will be better!

That said, I highly recommend reading: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) which is where I gleaned the above information. (Hands down, the most useful book I've ever read.)

Happy Regexing!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the name from a named capturing group, it becomes a numbered capturing group (which are numbered from left to right).

That means that `\1` will no longer backreference the group `(title|head)` but the group `(<(title|head)>)`, and that of course fails.

If you change the backreference to `\2`, it should work again (although your regex is syntactically invalid, missing at least one closing parenthesis, so I couldn't test it).

Comment: Actually, I think it needs to be changed to `\3` (See my answer for an explanation.)